# Direct speech inside another direct speech

Tags: parts-of-speech, speech

Please, I'm not sure how in American English this "direct speech inside another direct speech" should be written properly. Here it is this sentence:

> "He was five and a half meters from her and he was talking to her, softly. He told her: 'Please, try to calm yourself down. Everything will be OK'."

The use of the quotation marks is it correct? Thank you everybody in advance for your help!

Andrea Iovinelli

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your quote-within-a-quote is almost correctly punctuated.

- Most style books have the final period inside all quotes, so it would end with *Everything will be OK.'"* (Note: this is for American English and is the method cited in *Chicago Manual of Style, 13th ed.*)
- *he was talking to her* has its own subject, *he*. You would need to precede it with a semi-colon or a full stop. Or you would make drop the *he*. (Note: @Janusbahsjacquet calls the *and* a coordinating conjunction and thinks that it is fine as is.)

All in all:

> "He was five and a half meters from her. He was talking to her, softly. He told her: 'Please, try to calm yourself down. Everything will be OK.'"

Comment: Isn't this specifically American style? Or is it British style. I know the two are different but can't remember which is which.

Comment: *five and a half meters* is not a compound adjective. *five-and-one-half-meter-long* would be a compound adjective. [x and a half](https://www.full-proof.co.uk/articles/its-just-a-number/) - *half a mile or one and a half miles are not hyphenated*

Comment: 1) American style guides would generally have all punctuation inside the quotes; British ones would tend to only include punctuation in the quotes if it’s part of the quote. 2) _Five and a half_ is not a compound adjective and should not be hyphenated. 3) There is no need for _he was talking to her_ to be preceded by a semi-colon or full stop; a coordinator like _and_ (as used in the question) does the job just as well.

Comment: Mitch, the punctuation is American style, from Chicago Manual of Style, 13th ed.

Comment: I have edited to remove the compound adjective bullet and to add Janus's comment.

Comment: @Mitch With this *particular* sentence, the US and UK styles of punctuation are the same. (Aside from the double and single quotation marks being reversed.)

Comment: Sorry for having duplicate the topic! I have searched for, but I have searched for direct speech and not quote! Thanks everybody for the answers.